# Relation between TCP conversations and TCP streams in Wireshark

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark, tcpip

I have read about [Conversations](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChStatConversations.html) and [TCP Streams](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvFollowTCPSection.html#ChAdvFollowStream) but I'm still a bit unsure how they relate to each other if they are on the same layer.

For different layers, it's clear to me that e.g. an IP conversation can consist of multiple TCP streams.

Can a TCP conversation consist of several TCP streams? And opposite, can a TCP stream contain several TCP conversations? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, A [Conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Protocol_operation) occurs at the TCP level (Transport), and is synonymous with a TCP Connection between two ports.

A "TCP Stream" in this context, is the aggregation of the application messages that were passed in a conversation.  For instance, the stream in your link shows an interior host running a [UPNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play)-capable program, asking a router to forward port 5000 for it, and the router responding. So what you are actually is the data field of the TCP segment. For that reason I think it is poorly named. All the TCP information has been stripped away, leaving only the messages the software on both hosts send and receive. They might be [HTTP](https://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-methods) GETs and responses, [FTP](http://cr.yp.to/ftp.html) PUTs, [SMTP](http://cr.yp.to/smtp.html) MAILs, or any other application's native command language.

Personally, I'm not sure I like Wireshark's terminology in this documentation, but it does serve their perspective as a protocol analyzer well. An application does see a sockets connection between two endpoints as an IO stream, regardless of the underlying protocol.

On a side note, I would say that I disagree about IP having "conversations". IP doesn't carry the data necessary to maintain a virtual circuit, and leaves that up to an upper layer. TCP handles a strict circuit, and UDP handles a very loose one, leaving ordering, error correction, and flow control up to its application.

Answer (score 1):

*TCP* conversations and TCP streams *should* be at the same level, but, at least in some versions of Wireshark, they use different code to identify which packets are part of the conversation/stream, so they might give different answers.

One of them might, for example, treat all traffic between two endpoints (IP address/port pairs) as part of the same conversation/stream, even if one TCP connection between those two endpoints gets closed and another one happens to be opened up between the same two endpoints within the same capture (unlikely, as ports don't tend to get immediately reused, but not impossible), whereas the other might recognize the connection getting closed and show them as separate conversations/streams.

If they aren't using the same code, that's arguably a bug, but it might be one that nobody's fixed yet.

Obviously, *IP* "conversations", which are between two *IP* endpoints (two IP addresses) are different from TCP conversations/streams; as you note, there can be multiple TCP conversations, UDP conversations, etc. between two IP endpoints and thus multiple TCP/UDP/etc. conversations in the same IP conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the examples on the pages you link, it doesn't appear that the terms are functionally different.  Both seem to be the length of a single network connection.

The conversations page doesn't sum up multiple connections, it actually shows each individual one, with length of time and byte counts.  The stream window simply shows the details of the actual data sent.